# How to easily handle multiple similar codes

Tags: r

I want to search "831" from several columns （ECG1 to ECG20）. I wrote following codes, but them is so lengthy. I wonder if there is a simple and smart way to handle these codes.

Thank you very much.

af$af_exist <- 0

af <- af[ECG1 %in% c("831"), af_exist := 1]

af <- af[ECG2 %in% c("831"), af_exist := 1]

af <- af[ECG3 %in% c("831"), af_exist := 1]

af <- af[ECG4 %in% c("831"), af_exist := 1]

af <- af[ECG5 %in% c("831"), af_exist := 1]

af <- af[ECG6 %in% c("831"), af_exist := 1]

af <- af[ECG7 %in% c("831"), af_exist := 1]

af <- af[ECG8 %in% c("831"), af_exist := 1]

......

af <- af[ECG20 %in% c("831"), af_exist := 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
af %>%
  mutate(af_exists = +if_any(ECG1:ECG20,~.== "831"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer.  Could you tell me the diffierence between +if_any and if_any in this code (why do you use a + there)?

Comment: the `+` is just to turn the TRUE false to numeric. You can run the code without it